# add block to front page as a new section

Tags: blocks

I want to add block to front page as a new section On ours website, but I didn't succeed, please can you help me to do it? I used views to create it but when i create it doesn't show in blocks.

website: [www.awene.com](http://www.awene.com)  (is a kurdish website in iraq) designed by drupal 6.

Best regards

Comment: Did you properly save the view and also flushed cache?

Comment: I hope your view has display type of block?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a section available to add the block to or do you need to add a section to put the block in? To add a new section you'll need to edit the .info file for your theme and add the new section definition there. Also you'll need to modify the active page template for your homepage adding a new section to the template file. Then you can define where the block will appear and in the block config you can define that it only appear on the `<front>` page if that's the desired result.

Comment: Our website have a possibility to add new block to front page, but actually I don't have info aabout .info file and description here because before I heard some developer said just you can create a view and block to appear it on front page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first specify what region the block will be displayed in (most likely the Content region, I'm thinking in your case).  This can be done by going to the Blocks administration section.  Save once you've specified the appropriate region.

Then you need to configure the block.  On the same page, find the entry representing your block and click Configure (it should be off to the right).  Scroll down to the bottom, select the radio button "Only the listed pages" and enter "" in the big text area.  Click "Save block".  That should get the appropriate block into the appropriate region.

Afterwards though you'll need to use CSS to style the block correctly, but that's not really in the scope of this question.